# Deducing that polynomials span

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, analysis

Let us say that we are dealing with a countable family of polynomials with real coefficients in $n$ indeterminates that commute.  Are there any known/common nice systematic ways to tell if their span is the whole space of polynomials when they have a nice generating function?  What about the closure of the span in the supremum norm restricted to our polynomial space defined on a full-dimensional set such as $[0, 1]^n$? (I am not restricting only to methods that use the generating function.  But that is just one possibility.)